# Looped Parallel.For is not giving expected results

Tags: c#

I'm testing a Parallel.For loop inside another Parallel.For loop. The result expected to be numbers ascending by 1 unit from 1 to 500. But the output is always like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51

53
54
55
56
57

59

61
62
63
64
65

67
68
69

71

73
74
75
76
77

79
80
81

83
84
85
86
87

89
90
91
92
93
94
95

97
98
99

101

103
104


107

109
110
111

113
114
115
116

118
119


122
123
124
125

127
128
129

131
132

134
135

137

139
140


143
144

146
147

149

151
152
153
154
155



159
160
161

163
164


167

169
170
171

173
174
175



179

181

183
184
185

187
188
189

191


194
195

197

199


202
203
204

206
207

209




214
215
216


219

221

223
224


227

229
230
231

233
234


237

239


242

244
245

247

249

251



255

257
258
259
260


263

265



269

271
272


275


278
279

281




286
287

289



293

295
296


299
300


303

305

307

309

311


314




319

321

323



327
328
329


332


335



339

341
342
343





349
350
351







359







367
368
369





375

377

379



383


386


389

391



395



399




404




409



413





419


422






429

431







439
440








449









459









469









479









489









499
```

As you can see there's missings... I wrote small program for this. So here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace testProjectCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] numbersFromParallel = new string[500];

            ParallelOptions option1 = new ParallelOptions();
            option1.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10;
            ParallelOptions option2 = new ParallelOptions();
            option2.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10;

            Parallel.For(1, 51, option1, i =>
            {
                Parallel.For(1, 11, option2, g =>
                {
                    numbersFromParallel[(i * g) - 1] = ((i * g) - 1).ToString();
                });
            });

            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\tempArrayTest.txt", numbersFromParallel);
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the calculation you want is `(i - 1) * 51 + g`. Your question is actually mostly code, plus that massive resultset, you haven't really explained what or why you are doing this, I had to debug this myself

Comment: Please explain to us how you expect row 52 or 498 to be populated. i.e. which values of i and g will populate it?

Comment: Additionally, I very much doubt `Parallel` is helping you here. It is a 500 element array (i.e. tiny). Serial execution will be much faster. Plus you likely don't need an array at all. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of your index for the `numbersFromParallel` array is wrong. Assume you ranges are from `0` to `4` without the `-1` offset (so only `i*g`). Then you would generate the following values:

|  | g=0 | g=1 | g=2 | g=3 | g=4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **i=0** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **i=1** | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| **i=2** | 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| **i=3** | 0 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |
| **i=4** | 0 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 |

There are a lot of skipped numbers (like `5` or `10`) and some values are duplicates (like `0`, `3` or `12`).

What you want instead is an expression like `5*i + g` to get the values like these:

|  | g=0 | g=1 | g=2 | g=3 | g=4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **i=0 (0)** | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| **i=1 (5)** | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| **i=2 (10)** | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| **i=3 (15)** | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| **i=4 (20)** | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

So you have to adjust the `Parallel.For` loops like this:

```
int count_x = 50;
int count_y = 10;    
string[] numbersFromParallel = new string[count_x*count_y];

// ...

Parallel.For(0, count_x, option1, i =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, count_y, option2, g =>
    {
        int index = i*count_y + g;      
        numbersFromParallel[index] = index.ToString();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good, but `count_x` is named wrong, prob better to call it `upper_x`

Comment: Big thanks for your reply, Progman!:) But here's the one thing. Let's take an example when i = 50 and count_x = 50. When multiply those numbers the result is 2500. Outside of the numbersFromParallel array size, right? Since its size is count_x*count_y = 50 * 10 = 500.

Comment: @5ama7 Correct, I fixed it.

Comment: Great! This worked! Thank you very much, Progman! Wish you all the good things!:)